# Solr fuzzy match has better score than exact match

Tags: solr, lucene

I'm doing a fuzzy search in Solr, and in rare cases the exact match has score lower than a fuzzy match. I even found a reason using debugQuery: fuzzy match has matched 3 different words, and exact match matched only one. So the "sum of" 3 matches got better value, than one. [Here](http://pastebin.com/nACy2Sm5) is part of the "explain".

Is there any way to configure Solr for ranking exact matches higher than fuzzy, even in this case?

P.S. I already using `omitTermFreqAndPositions="true" omitNorms="true"`, but it doesn't help if we have a fuzzy match against different words.

Comment: Are you looking for a specific solution? That looks right. That is why you need to do a boolean query of exact match with higher boost with an OR query of fuzzy query so that exact matches rank higher.

Comment: This looks like valid solution, I'll do this way, if I don't find another. But it seems that it will be double work for Solr, perform two searches.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to do a boolean query of exact match with higher boost with a Boolean OR query of fuzzy query so that exact matches rank higher. Do not worry about double work for solr. It is built for very complex Lucene query trees. Using a combination of queries to get relevancy ranking expected is common practice. If you agree pl. accept my answer.

Comment: Hey Arun, What an answer +1, solved my problem in 5 seconds :)

Comment: Thanks arun, did `ngramText:"sementes" OR sementes` and it worked! Why isn't this the default on Solr?

Comment: arun, actually it didn't worked right. doing this actually made it return all results on all searches, and not limiting itselt to the matches :(

Comment: @brauliobo query should be like `field:(value~2 OR value^3)`

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and solved this by using `copyField` and doing 
exact and fuzzy (phonetic in my case) matching on separate fields.

Then used `EdisMax`'s `qf` field to give higher weight for matches on exact field
vs ones on fuzzy matching.